# Как я могу сортировать по таксонам с помощью вкладок? WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-query

Как я могу сортировать по таксонам с помощью вкладок без архива?. Просто с перезагрузкой страници (или без нее).

HTML:

```
  <ul class="portfolio-sorting">
    <li><a href="" class="active">All Rooms</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Entertainment</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Restaurants</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Sport</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Service</a></li>
  </ul>
```

PHP (WordPress цикл):

```
    <?php $gallerys_posts = new WP_Query($args); //Аргумент $args должен быть получен из функции[set_arges]
    wp_reset_query();


if( $gallerys_posts->have_posts() ) :
  while ( $gallerys_posts->have_posts() ) :
    $gallerys_posts->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 shuffle-item filtered">
      <div class="portfolio-item">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_id());?>">
          <?php if ( get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_id()) )  { ?>
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_id(), array(620, 423 )); ?>
          <?php } ?>
          <div class="portfolio-overlay">
            <div class="caption">
              <?php echo get_title(); ?>
              <span>
                <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

PHP (функция возвращает масив с настройками для вышеуказанного цикла):

```
<?php function set_arges($type_filter = 'all') {
  switch ($type_filter) {
    case 'all':
      $args= array( 
          'post_type'           => 'gallerys',
          'posts_per_page'      => '-1',
          'tax_query'           => array(
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'gallerys_type',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => 'all-rooms'
            )
          )
      );
      return $args;
      break;

    case 'entertainment':
        $args= array( 
          'post_type'           => 'gallerys',
          'posts_per_page'      => '-1',
          'tax_query'           => array(
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'gallerys_type',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => 'entertainment'
            )
          )
        );
        return $args;
        break;

    case 'restaurants':
      $args= array( 
          'post_type'           => 'gallerys',
          'posts_per_page'      => '-1',
          'tax_query'           => array(
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'gallerys_type',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => 'restaurants'
            )
          )
      );
      return $args;
      break;

    case 'sport':
      $args= array(
          'post_type'           => 'gallerys',
          'posts_per_page'      => '-1',
          'tax_query'           => array(
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'gallerys_type',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => 'sport'
            )
          )
      );
      return $args;
      break;

    case 'services':
      $args= array( 
          'post_type'           => 'gallerys',
          'posts_per_page'      => '-1',
          'tax_query'           => array(
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'gallerys_type',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => 'services'
            )
          )
      );
      return $args;
      break;
  }
}
```

По умолчанию параметр $filter_type принимает значения «all», и все сообщения отображаются, но при нажатии на вкладку значение должно меняться, сообщения тоже должны меняться.
Как это можно реализовать? Большое спасибо!!!

Comment: Плагинов есть много по данной теме, но как сделать все это самому, ручками???

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverlow ru! То, что вы хотите, реализуют ajax- запросами. Об ajax в WordPress на русском тут: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: спасибо, очень интересная стаття, надеюсь она решит мою проблему...